# BranchSDK: User session has not been initialized

Tags: java, android, branch.io

I have problem with BranchSDK, during initialization i receive error:

`12-28 13:50:22.203 D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://api2.branch.io/v1/install 0b 1136ms,
12-28 13:50:22.204 I/FirebasePerformance: Did not receive a HTTP Response Code
12-28 13:50:22.204 W/FirebasePerformance: Unable to process the PerfMetric due to missing or invalid values. See earlier log statements for additional information on the specific missing/invalid values.
12-28 13:50:22.208 E/BranchNetworkClient: Error in doRestfulGet(https://api2.branch.io/v1/install)
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x63395a88: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x5d9ce808:0x00000000)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:449)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:318)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:282)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:167)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.riversoft.eventssion.network.BranchNetworkClient.doRestfulPost(BranchNetworkClient.java:59)
        at io.branch.referral.network.BranchRemoteInterface.make_restful_post(BranchRemoteInterface.java:136)
        at io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchPostTask.doInBackground(Branch.java:2860)
        at io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchPostTask.doInBackground(Branch.java:2835)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x63395a88: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x5d9ce808:0x00000000)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
            ... 29 more`

I tried:
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/issues/552
and:

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new 
ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)  
    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
    .cipherSuites(
          CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
          CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
          CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
    .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder() 
    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
    .build();
```

P.S. This is problem is on API19, but API 28, 27, 25, 23 all is good worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 3.0.3 and below, helped me only add a string when initializing the BranchSDK: `ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(context);`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm the SDK version that you are using? As our latest SDK versions had some TLS related changes.

Please refer to: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/releases

where release 3.0.0 had some TLS related changes.Please update the Branch SDK and write to integrations@branch.io if the issue still persists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on base application oncreate method

```
 Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

For React Native Expo IOS (`react-native-branch@5.4.0`, `@config-plugins/react-native-branch@5.0.0`, `expo@48.0.10`) just make sure to implement

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <RNBranch/RNBranch.h>
  
@implementation AppDelegate
  
// Initialize the Branch Session at the top of existing application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Uncomment this line to use the test key instead of the live one.
    // [RNBranch useTestInstance];
    [RNBranch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions isReferrable:YES];
    NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
    //...
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    [RNBranch application:application openURL:url options:options];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
   [RNBranch continueUserActivity:userActivity];
   return YES;
}
```

in `AppDelegate.mm` file.
In official documentation it use

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    [RNBranch application:app openURL:url options:options];
    return YES;
}
```

but it throws `use of undeclared identifier 'app'` error in my environment. I had to change `app` to `application` to force this work.